# Prevent domain user making changes on desktop

Tags: windows-10, desktop, roaming-profiles

I have a problem with desktop icons for domain users. I have about 150 domain PC's with the same config (programs, icons, same hardware, OS - win 10, etc). The problem is that users are saving some files on the desktop and it is a bit messy after some time. How to stop it?

I was thinking about using Public Desktop folder, but if I join the computer to a domain, it is creating a new folder for that user. Using roaming profiles (mandatory, without ability to change anything) instead won't work, because they are using the same domain user. I was looking for some GPO that would prevent the user from making changes to a certain folder, but can't find anything.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at the following articles:

Prevent user to save in desktop

> Workaround this would be - set user for roaming profile and redirect the desktop folder in network share. Once you redirect desktop folder to network share this will create \server\share\deskto\username and remove the right permission there. That will prevent user to save item in desktop.

[Solution by Madal](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverGP/thread/042a06f5-bf36-48ae-b982-77cd75f56cab)

VBScript to prevent users from saving files to the desktop - [source](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7198b23b-35f2-4396-a23b-e687741d275e/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer should contain all relevant information in the answer body. 
 This means you should quote and cite the relevant information from the links you provided.  Link-only answers are not considered to be helpful.  Your answer should specifically answer the author's question, saying the author (and the reader) should read a couple links, does not answer the question.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited my answer. Hope this helps.